# Show integrals equal for these 3 forms on $\Bbb{S}^7$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\theta,\gamma$ be $3-$forms on $\Bbb{S}^7$. show that

$$\int_{\Bbb{S}^7} \theta \, \wedge d \gamma = \int_{\Bbb{S}^7} d \theta \, \wedge \gamma$$

My thoughts: Subtract the LHS from the RHS to show

$$\int_{\Bbb{S}^7} d \theta \, \wedge \gamma + (-1) \theta \, \wedge d \gamma= \int_{\Bbb{S}^7} d(\theta  \wedge \gamma)=\int_{\partial \Bbb{S}^7} \theta \wedge \gamma = 0$$

Where the first equality is by the anti derivation property of the exterior derivative, the second equality is by Stoke's Theorem, the last equality is because the boundary of $\Bbb{S}^7$ is the empty set thus the integral is zero. Is this correct? And we have that $\theta  \wedge \gamma$ is a $7-1=6-$form on $\Bbb{S}^7$ thus Stokes Theorem can be applied.

Comment: If you wanted to be a bit picky, you should write $(-1)^3$, since $\theta$ is a 3-form. But otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I actually wrote that down in my work on my paper! @F.Conrad how funny!!

Comment: I even thought so, since you put $( $ and $)$ around your $-1$, instead of just using the minus sign.

Comment: One correction: your first equality does not follow from the definition of the wedge product. Instead, it's the antiderivation property of the exterior derivative.

Comment: aha, good catch! @JackLee btw, Im enjoying learning out of your text for the first time before I begin graduate school! The intro to smooth manifolds.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: As a remark, this is basically integration by parts but for differential forms. Stokes' theorem is often thought of as a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, and I agree that it is, but also integration by parts in several variables also looks exactly like this, but without the (-1)^k term that appears due to the fact that wedge is graded-commutative, and remembers orientation.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger  wow I didn't even think about it like that, good point!